# Attach camera to scriptable object in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to ScriptableObjects, and I have kind of a noob question.
I've read that scriptable objects are used to store data, and can be used to even store a single variable. So here's what I did:
I created a script like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/MainCamera", 
order = 1)]
public class MainCamera : ScriptableObject
{
    public Camera Camera;
}
```

I then created a scriptable object from it in my Assets folder, like described here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptableObject.html

And now I want to assign the Main camera to that Camera variable in the inspector.
However, the selection menu only shows "none", but no camera.

**How do I assign the camera to the camera variable in my scriptable object?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **not** directly attach Scene references to `ScriptableObject`s or actually any assets.

But you can go the other way round: Give the Camera the `ScriptableObject` reference and make it tell it's own reference to that `ScriptableObject`:

```
// This attribute makes this classes messages be executed also in editmode
// (= also of not in playmode)
[ExecuteInEditModo]

// Assure there is a Camera component
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class CameraSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MainCamera mainCameraAsset;

    // Called on initialize
    // With [ExecuteInEditModo] also called on recompile
    private void Awake ()
    {
        mainCameraAsset.Camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
}
```

And reference your `MainCamera` instance in `mainCameraAsset`.

---

Is there a reason you don't use [Camera.main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html) instead of the `ScriptableObject`?

---

**Map for different Scenes**

In case you want to archive something like a "manager asset" storing a different `Camera` reference for each scene as requested in the comments (I hope I understood you correctly) I would change your `MainCamera` to something like

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/MainCamera", 
order = 1)]
public class MainCamera : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<SceneCameraPair> SceneCameraPairs = new List<SceneCameraPair>();

    public Dictionary<string, Camera> sceneToCamera = new Dictionary<string, Camera>();

    public void AddPair(SceneCameraPair pair)
    {
        if(SceneCameraPairs.Contains(pair)) return;

        SceneCameraPairs.Add(pair);
        sceneToCamera[pair.scene.path] = pair.camera;
    }

    public void ResetPairs()
    {
        SceneCameraPairs.Clear();
        sceneToCamera.Clear();
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class SceneCameraPair
{
    public Scene scene;
    public Camera camera;
}
```

and in the setter use [SceneManager.GetActiveScene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html)

```
// This attribute makes this classes messages be executed also in editmode
// (= also of not in playmode)
[ExecuteInEditModo]

// Assure there is a Camera component
[RequireComponent(typeof(Camera))]
public class CameraSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private MainCamera mainCameraAsset;

    // Called on initialize
    // With [ExecuteInEditModo] also called on recompile
    private void Awake ()
    {
        mainCameraAsset.AddPair(SceneManager.GetActiveScene,  GetComponent<Camera>();
    }
}
```

Than later in a scene you can either use the list with [FirstOrDefault](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.6) (which doesn't throw an exception but return `null` if item not found) and the [Scene.path](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-path.html) (because the scene name might be the same and you can't compare `scene` directly since it's instance is not the same as the referenced one) like e.g.

```
var camera = mainCameraReference.SceneCameraPairs.FirstOrDefault(pair => pair.scene.path == ScaneManager.GetActiveScene().path);
```

or the dictionary like

```
 var camera = mainCameraReference.sceneToCamera[ScaneManager.GetActiveScene().path];
```

---

**Various Types**

To be able to store various references of different types (assuming only one per type) you could do something like e.g.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Data", menuName = "ScriptableObjects/Data", order = 1)]
public class References : ScriptableObject
{
    public Camera mainCamera;
    public CharacterController controller;
    public Transform transform;

    // fix for the generic methods
    // a bit dirty maybe but should work
    public void Set(Component component)
    {
        if(component.GetType() == typeof(Camera))
        {
            mainCamera = (Camera) component;
        } 
        else if(component.GetType() == typeof(CharacterController))
        {
            controller = (CharacterController) component;
        }
        else if(component.GetType() == typeof(Transform))
        {
            transform = (Transform) component;
        }
    }

    public void Set(Camera camera)
    {
        mainCamera = camera;
    }

    public void Set(CharacterController characterController )
    {
        controller = characterController ;
    }

    public void Set(Transform characterTransform)
    {
        transform = characterTransform;
    }

    // or simply all at once
    public void Set(Camera camera, CharacterController characterController, Transform characterTransform)
    {
        mainCamera = camera;
        controller = characterController;
        transform = characterTransform;
    }

    // etc
}
```

Than you could have one base setter class like

```
public abstract class SetterBase<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component
{
    // unfortunately you can not serialize generics in 
    // the inspector so for now we stick with only one single ScriptableObject
    public References references;

    privtae void Awake()
    {
        SetReference<T>();
    }

    private void SetReference<T>() where T : Component
    {
        var component = GetComponent<T>();
        references.Set(component);
    }
}
```

Now you can inherit implementations for every type you need / that is present in `References` like

```
public CameraSetter : SetterBase<Camera>
{
    // doesn't have to do anything else ... but could
}
```

and

```
public TransformSetter : SetterBase<Transform>
{
    // doesn't have to do anything else ... but could
}
```

etc

**Or alternatively** 
 (and that's why I added one setter for everything) you could let it be handled all by one single manager

```
public class ReferenceSetter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public References references;

    // Reference those in the inspector as usual
    public Camera camera;
    public Transform transform;
    public CharacterController controller;

    private void Awake()
    {
        references.Set(camera, controller, transform);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I won't be able to attach anything in scene, and need to get a reference via script? Does that mean I won't be able to attach a character controller to a ScriptableObject either?

There's no real reason, other than experimentation for now.

Comment: Yes you will have to write a setter somehow for anything you want to get from the Scene to `ScriptableObject`s. Or use some dependency injection like e.g. [zenject](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/zenject-dependency-injection-ioc-17758)

Comment: Do I keep the camera then stored as a property?
Or how would I implement this?

Comment: @Thrindil what do you mean exactly?

Comment: "Yes you will have to write a setter somehow for anything you want to get from the Scene to ScriptableObject" => This made me think about storing it in a property, but your approach is different. Assume I want to create a scriptable object which stores 10 scene references, do I write a setter for each?
Or how would this be best approached?

Comment: You want like a map to different scene camera for each scene? I hope I understood that correctly - updated my answer. Otherwise simply use the same setter but create various ScriptableObjects like e.g. `Scene1_mainCamera`, `Scene1_menuCamera`, `Scene2_camera` etc. And if you are speaking about different component types ... yes you need a setter for each type

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, that's not what I'm looking for.
With 10 scene references I mean 10 different scene objects, something like this:

public Camera Camera;
public CharacterController CharacterController;
public Transform CharacterTransform;
etc.

Comment: yeah than you need a different setter for each

Comment: See my latest update `Various Types` .. that might help you along

Comment: On your latest update, in the SetterBase script in the Awake method, I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'Set(T)', candidates are:
void Set(Camera)
void Set(CharacterController)
void Set(Transform), and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry didn't think that through ... it would require a generic method also in the scriptable object .. I added a method for the generic version

Comment: Thank you.
Just wanted to let you know that I had to edit the SetterBase<T> class before I could get it to work, so the declaration is
public abstract class SetterBase<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Component
instead of just public abstract class SetterBase<T> : MonoBehaviour